# Eclipse CDT QT4 auto-complete not working

Tags: c++, qt4, eclipse-cdt

I cannot get auto-complete to work with Eclipse CDT and QT4.  Whatever I try, auto-complete does not work for me!  I can create and run QT GUI applications no problem, so the plugin must be installed... I do not know why the auto-complete does not work... For that matter, auto complete does not work at all?  What setting am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to setup include paths in the project properties, this will happen automatically if you use a pro file with qmake and let Eclipse import it as a Makefile based project.

Comment: All the includes seem to show up?  on the right panel, an incluse folder gets created with /usr/lib/qt44/inlcude and all of the sub dirs?